# Domain URL with Querystring without page name

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a domain mydomain.com which hosts asp.net website. I am creating some dynamic user's page on the company specific. If i open any page so it will show like mydomain.com/career.aspx?pagename=testpage.

But I want to change my URL and make it user friendly like mydomain.com/testpage1 or mydomain.com/testpage2 etc...

Can you anyone please explain in a step by step to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Asp.net routing. I'd start here:

[Walkthrough: Using ASP.NET Routing in a Web Forms Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Esentially, you'll end up putting something like this in your `Global.asax`:

```
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute("Customers", "Customers", "~/Customers.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: We wont use page name also. Only i want domain name and query string

Comment: Exactly. My answer stands.

Comment: Yes James. I have tried the same but without page name its not possible. It's been such like "mydomain.com/career/anypage" but I need this  "mydomain.com/anypage"

Comment: Dynamic routing is the only way to accomplish this. You just need to define your routes properly.